# Unable to get data from WCF service using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, wcf, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using a web application where user pass one argument to the service and it will return string datatype which is query result. In the service i am using Entity Framework to query based on the user input but i am unable to get the data instead throwing an **exception** in my **webapplication** saying.....
 **The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.**
Webapplication and service are two different solutions.
Code in My WCF service

```
public string GetFunctionality(string UserId)
    {
        string strRoleName = string.Empty;
        objEntity = new SYMPHONY_TVEntities();
        var Function = from t1 in objEntity.Users join t2 in objEntity.User_Role on t1.Role equals t2.User_Role1 where t1.UserID == UserId select t2;
        var UserName = from it in objEntity.Users where it.UserID == UserId select it;
        //Here i am getting exception
        User_Role objRole = Function.First();
        User objUser = UserName.First();
        if (objRole.User_Function != null && objUser.User_Name != null)
        {
            strRoleName = objRole.User_Function + "$" + objUser.User_Name;
        }
        return strRoleName;
    }
```

My connection string WCF service

```
<add name="SYMPHONY_TVEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UsersModel.csdl|res://*/UsersModel.ssdl|res://*/UsersModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=inhi1u-hd0212\;Initial Catalog=&quot;SYMPHONY TV&quot;;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8315680/860243) on your service to know the actual exception.

Comment: I am getting error the underlying provider faild on open how to resolve it

Comment: Provide some code for the wcf operation that you are calling which is throwing the exception.

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: Is the entity framework edmx in the same project as your Wcf service?

Comment: Yes in the service itself

Comment: Connect to the database directly using the credentials in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks ok. The exception says it is unable to connect to the db. This means your connection string might be wrong, please verify your connection string. If this fails try adding this line of code after your `objEntity`. ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081776/860243))

```
objEntity = new SYMPHONY_TVEntities();
objEntity.Connection.Open();
```

Comment: I don't think problem in the connection string just have a look on it. But none resolved my issue.

Comment: Windows authentication is not working when i add database in ServerExplorer instead if i give sqlauthentication and add database its working fine is there any restriction?