# enabling ssl for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I'm trying to enable ssl for my WCF, I'm doing exact steps from this tutorial:

https://github.com/geersch/WcfEnableSsl

I even tried to run example application (https://github.com/geersch/WcfEnableSsl)

but in my app and in the example app i get

```
 fault exception was unhandled

The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

at this line

```
                var customers = proxy.GetCustomers();
```

can anyone help with this?

EDIT
I added a printscreen of an error with details

[image: error]

Comment: So what is the exact error?

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in that error to open up permissions on IIS to show the actual error.

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or) for details how to do that.

Comment: in my web.config i have turn on <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>