# Apply service behavior to Service Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config, servicebehavior

I have added to my web application a Service Reference to a .svc web service on a remote server.
When I call a method from this webservice i get the following error.

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server

First question: IncludeExceptionDetailinFaults must be turned on my server or on the remote server that the .svc service is hosted?

Second question: If IncludeExceptionDetailinFaults must be turned on, on my server how can I configure the web.config file properly to apply the behavior  for the Service Reference I have added. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or) describes the way to apply it to a service in the web.config but in my web.config there are no services defined since I added a Service Reference from the solution explorer. (Only bindings and client are automatically defined under serviceModel node)
Another thing to note is that when i run the application locally on my laptop in visual studio debugging I don't get the error. But when I publish the solution to my server I get the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property must be set on the hosting server, as it's the server that determines whether to include exception details, not the client. The question you linked to shows how to do that.

Comment: By "hosting server" you mean the server that the .svc webservice is hosted or the server that my web application is hosted?

Comment: If needs to be set in the config of the .svc service