# Getting underlying exception from third party WCF - SOAP Exception

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a client connecting to third part WCF Service (I have access to the web.config or service but not code).
The Third Party throws a SOAP Exception because the faulting assembly isn't marked as serializable - "Type Assembly not marked as serializable".

Is there anyway I can get the underlying exception detail that was thrown and not faulted on the WCF Service via configuration edit or other means?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **includeExceptionDetailInFaults** in your web.config file.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or).