# can't upload my data in server using Web Service in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the
>   exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs.

I don't  if the problem is from the server or  in the system

this is my stack trace

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.ServiceReferenceBilling.IService.RequestGenerateBill(String rclid, String ruserid, String rbrid, String rdatefrom, String rdateto, String rduedate, String careof, Int64[] rairbillsids, Decimal rNet, Decimal rRvat, Int32 rstatement, String bir)
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.ServiceReferenceBilling.ServiceClient.RequestGenerateBill(String rclid, String ruserid, String rbrid, String rdatefrom, String rdateto, String rduedate, String careof, Int64[] rairbillsids, Decimal rNet, Decimal rRvat, Int32 rstatement, String bir) in C:\Users\REGIME\Desktop\New folder\JRS_Online_Apps_III\JRS_Online_Apps_III\Service References\ServiceReferenceBilling\Reference.vb:line 254
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.CreateBillingForm.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\REGIME\Desktop\New folder\JRS_Online_Apps_III\JRS_Online_Apps_III\Billing\CreateBillingForm.vb:line 238
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at JRS_Online_Apps_III.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

> Correct me if i'm wrong ... is the alter query can corrupt the whole
>   database, with relationship because I alter table but I forgot to set
>   up the constraint and relations

I tried put the code in my project no luck it always give me the error
 
 https://ibb.co/ccLfUb 
 
 https://ibb.co/eTghsw

Comment: The error message tells you what to do to get more information.  Did you do it?

Comment: I think it tells me that something was wrong in web service that created, I don't know how to modify it because I'm new to this kind of error and that service was created by another programmer not me so I don't know how to modify it... btw I just hired to create new program but that system  was currently use then that error happen I don't know how to do I just check deadlock in the server but it's ok I just check other database and anythins is ok..

Comment: If you don't know how to do something then search for information on how to do it. I get the feeling that you haven't even tried to find out. Have you bothered to Google "IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults" or "ServiceBehaviorAttribute"?

Comment: actually I googled it and all I found  IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false  in my app.config then I tried to set it to true but nothing happens it only redirect me to the error but I don't know what suposed to do in that error. the error is from the variables from the web services by the way the error is from the client side

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or), which was the first match when I searched for "IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults"?

Comment: I just read it, I comment again if there change in the program I hope this gonna be ok. thanks for the replies

Comment: @jmcilhinney I just googled everything and I found this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx supposedly I kinda get what fault exception says it turns out I can get the error because of fault handling exception but that;s not mean the issue was solve the problem is it says that no conenction to the server.. does it mean that the service was corrupted? and no values came from my system?

Comment: I successfyllu upload and retrieve data from my server if I use (Take offline) mode but if I live my server then upload some data  the errors appears.. I change the web.config andapp.config maxbuffer maxpool so o nand so forth...  Is the active connection was the problem? because it turns out my active connection count into 150 + . but if i go offline that only me have the access to the server ther was no error ..

Answer (score 0):

Good day it's been years that this question of mine needs to be answer.

so.. the problem here is that the `Web Api` appears to be `reconfigured` (i'm so newbie way back then that I didn't know how to check a `Web API` coz I only do offline base application that does not use Web API's, now that I know how `API` works, problem was the API not configure correctly by the old programmer (by the way I only re-program the application on  that company),

Problem Cause:

`datatype-mismatch`: from `int` to `nvarchar`
that's the only problem. I only change the data type of a column and the problem has gone.

also another thing you can encouter into when there's a timeout in your connection. I also resolve this using `Indexing`. You can change the  `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` = `false` to `true` so that you can see the errors you encounter.