# IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults in code for a single service contract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've seen the previous questions ---

[Turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or)

[Set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to true in code for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483178/set-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-to-true-in-code-for-wcf)

Unfortunately, both these questions fail to solve my purpose.

I want to enable IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults for only a single contract out the many contracts that a particular ServiceHost may be dealing with. A ServiceHost may have multiple endpoints for different contracts, **but I only need to enable this debug feature for any single one of them**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IncludeExceptionDeatilsInFaults can not be configured to specific contract, it's part of the ServiceBehavior.

You could specify a custom fault, catch all exceptions in the operation where you want to return all exception info the client and return your specific fault.

Beware of returning a fault with the original exception object, because some exceptions cannot be serialized. If you create your own fault, you can add the exception message and stacktrace to it.